# Mark Horowitz Computing's energy problem - methodology

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, ddr

I have a question about the Mark Horowitz paper: *Computing’s Energy Problem
(and what we can do about it)*. In the paper, the author breaks down the sources of energy loss in modern computing systems.

What is the methodology they used to obtain these results? or could have used? Is it some sort of simulation?

Comment: That paper contains quite a lot of numbers and statements. Which premise ones are you wondering about? Presumably, the authors got most of their information from the sources that they cite; have you checked those?

Comment: I have read some of the references, yes. However, to my knowledge, they do not sufficiently explain these numbers. For example, the CPU DB reference does contain a plethora of information on microprocessors, but not on systems. Thus DRAM energy is not included. Additionally, they quote energy at a macro level of a whole processor, not broken down by cache/control/operation. I do want to note however, that my background is higher level computer architecture, and I do have a hard time reading VLSI papers.